# How can I pass a ref to HOC that uses onClickOutside('react-onclickoutside')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use `onClickOutside('react-onclickoutside')` for my HOC and I can't pass ref for this HOC, I have something like below and an **error** appears:

```
const inputRef = useRef();
....
<SomeCompontnt
    inputRef={inputRef}
    items={items}
    onSelect={onSelect}
    value={selectedItem}
 />
....
export default onClickOutside(forwardRef(
(props, inputRef) => <MyHoc inputRef={inputRef} {...props} />)
);
....
```

Errors

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReactComponent' of
>   undefined
>       at onClickOutside.render (react-onclickoutside.es.js?7e48:325)

[image]

Comment: your code doesn't even show the property isReactComponent where the error occurs, provide more info.

Comment: could it be related to this? https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside/issues/327

Answer (score 0):

try this:
you can see MyHoc onClick output in OnclickoutsideDemo MyHookClick console

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import onClickOutside from "react-onclickoutside";

class OnclickoutsideDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const options = this.state.showOptions ? (
      <MyHookClick
        onClick={e => console.log(e)}
        handleClickOutside={() => this.setState({ showOptions: false })}
      />
    ) : null;

    return (
      <div>
        <span
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState({ showOptions: !this.state.showOptions })
          }
        >
          Click Me
        </span>
        {options}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const MyHoc = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} onClick={e => props.onClick("HaHa")}>
    Click Me to see HaHa in console !
  </div>
));

const MyHookClick = onClickOutside(props => (
  <MyHoc ref={props.inputRef} {...props} />
));

export default OnclickoutsideDemo;

render(<OnclickoutsideDemo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Answer updated, see answer output here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-onclickoutside-kew28